# ActiveRecord doesn't save user name and email value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

My db/schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150826120752) do

  create_table "microposts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

My migration file for users db/migrate/20150826113925_create_users.rb

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

My User model file app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name, :email

  has_many :microposts
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true    

end
```

in rails console:

```
tom = User.new(name: "Tom", email: "tom@email.com")       
=> #<User:0x007f8a84ab1fb0 id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
tom.save

(0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2015-09-07 15:55:20.944767"], ["updated_at", "2015-09-07 15:55:20.944767"]]
   (0.0ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
=> true
User.all
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
=> [#<User:0x007f8a84691a98 id: 4, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: Mon, 07 Sep 2015 15:55:20 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Mon, 07 Sep 2015 15:55:20 UTC +00:00>]
```

Why aren't the name and email attributes saved?

Comment: If you did `tom = User.create(name: "Tom", email: "tom@email.com")` does the same thing happen?

Comment: I would try removing ```attr_accessor :name, :email```

Comment: @laertiades - Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `ActiveRecord` there's no need to define `attr_accessor`, unless you're trying to create virtual attributes. ActiveRecord defines these getters/setters for the attributes based on the columns on your database.

When you set `attr_accessor` on your class, you're basically overriding what ActiveRecord provides for you and hence not using the functionality that it normally does, which is saving those attributes to the database.

Removing the `attr_accessor` from your class should fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would try removing `attr_accessor :name, :email`

Comment: For explanations why: this line overrides default active record setter and getter. Those are defined within an anonymous module which is created and included within the class when rails establish a connection and inspect the table. `attr_accessor` defines a method directly within the class and it takes precedence over the method from included methods during method lookout.

Answer (score -1):

if you delete this line `attr_accessor :name, :email` it's should be work
with rails 4 you don't need this.

Comment: I do understand you want to get points and all, but this is not the best way. Pretty much you simply copied the answer which has been provided couple of minutes before - this will not help anyone, does not expand community knowledge and is an ugly way of getting free points. If you have more points (and you will be able to see deleted answers) you will notice some people removes their correct answers just because they posted it couple of seconds after another, almost identical one.

Comment: I'm not sure that understand you. I put my answer 2 min before laertiades's answer. I think he is before me in the list just because someone vote for him and not for me? Maybe I'm wrong. (sorry for my poor english)

Comment: You answered exactly two minutes and 3 seconds after his answer (You can get an exact time the answer has been posted by hovering over `answered xxx ago`). Unless for some reason 16:19 is 2 minutes before 16:17?

Comment: You right. When I begin to write my answer, I don't think his answer was published. Whatever, I think StandardNerd has his solution ;-)